Loading Jupyter notebook file on linux in my school computer system
So the assignment I have is in a jupyter notebook file. I had to secure copy the file and related directories over to a directory on my school's virtual network. I then try to open the notebook with "jupyter notebook notebookname.ipynb" and I get a kind of menu system but I don't know how to actually access the notebook file from this menu. I'm not sure how to proceed.
I tried chatgpt to answer it and it just says to copy the url at the bottom and I did that and I got a "local host refuses to connect" answer.

I don't know if you're using and IDE but personally for editing .ipynb files I use the "Jupyter" extension from vscode. (Not really an answer to your question though so putting it here as a comment)
